# Sharedpreference value not being displayed in UI

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I'm retrieving User data from the Sharedpreference, but unable to display it in the UI text section, but only if i hit the hot reload the retreived data is showing in the UI text.

```
 String username = "";

@override
  void initState() {
    getPrefs();
    super.initState();
  }
getPrefs() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    username = prefs.getString('user_name') ?? '';
  }
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
 body: Container(
 child: Text(username == "" ? "Username" : username, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),),
)
);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getPrefs` is called asynchronously. Therefore the UI is drawn **before** the username value is retrieved.

To fix that just call `setState` once you have the username value, which will force the UI to refresh.

Here is a quick implementation:

```
getPrefs() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  setState(() {
    username = prefs.getString('user_name') ?? '';
  });
}
```